# Add dynamic input form angular without ng-repat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, angularjs-scope, frontend

I'm adding several fields to a form dynamically, for a collection of Symfony, but the angular form doesn't detect the new field for validate it.

The new field has ng-model and ng-required etc... but hasn't the class ng-valid, ng-valid-required etc...

There is some method of angular look for the DOM again if no new fields to add to the scope ?

Thanks.

Comment: look at this link : https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform

Comment: The title of post say: without ng-repeat and your link is with ng-repeat...

Comment: are you directly adding dom elements in form? then you need to compile it. Look here :http://jsfiddle.net/jugnu_pathak/okqjs6Ls/

Comment: Yeah ! was good ! Thanks.